# In batch file, how to pass parameter to program which has started runnning

Tags: batch-file

I want to loop over a set of data in a folder and pass the data as parameters to a program in a batch file. The problem is that when the program has finished running, it expects the user to input a keystroke to terminate it, eg 'q'. How do I send the keystroke to the program in this case?

This is as far as I got

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do program.exe %%a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send input to a problem usually via `echo`:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (echo q|program.exe %%a)
```

This won't help if the program expects actual keyboard input, though. It only works if it reads from the standard input stream.